# How to get the GNU-grub menu, after installing ubuntu, along side windows

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

After installing ubuntu (dual booting, along side ,windows) on my notebook inspiron 15 R  , I did not get the grub menu, to choose between the operating systems.

what should I do now to get menu, for choosing the operating system.

I am not that professional, so I want a descriptive answer ...

Comment: Please boot the live USB again, make sure you have a working internet connection. Then follow the instructions here (2nd option) https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair in order to install and run "Boot-Repair". Do NOT apply any fix but generate the report (Create a bootinfo summary), [edit] your question and paste the URL there so we can see *how* it was installed and *what* can be done.

Comment: Does your firmware settings allow you to select OS to boot?